# Trouble overloading extraction operator for custom PriorityQueue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, data-stream, extraction-operator

I am trying to overload `operator>>` for a custom `PriorityQueue` class I've been writing, code is below:

```
/**
 * @brief Overloaded stream extraction operator.
 *
 * Bitshift operator>>, i.e. extraction operator. Used to write data from an input stream
 * into a targeted priority queue instance. The data is written into the queue in the format,
 *
 * \verbatim
 [item1] + "\t" + [priority1] + "\n"
 [item2] + "\t" + [priority2] + "\n"
 ...
 * \endverbatim
 *
 * @todo Implement functionality for any generic Type and PriorityType.
 * @warning Only works for primitives as template types currently!
 * @param inStream Reference to input stream
 * @param targetQueue Instance of priority queue to manipulate with extraction stream
 * @return Reference to input stream containing target queue data
 */
template<typename Type, typename PriorityType> std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inStream, PriorityQueue<Type, PriorityType>& targetQueue) {

    // vector container for input storage
    std::vector< std::pair<Type, PriorityType> > pairVec;
    // cache to store line input from stream
    std::string input;

    std::getline(inStream, input);

    if (typeid(inStream) == typeid(std::ifstream)) {
        inStream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    // loop until empty line
    while (!input.empty()) {
        unsigned int first = 0;
        // loop over input cache
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
            // if char at index i of cache is a tab, break from loop
            if (input.at(i) == '\t')
                break;
            ++first;
        }
        std::string data_str = input.substr(0, first);
        // convert from std::string to reqd Type
        Type data = atoi(data_str.c_str());

        std::string priority_str = input.substr(first);
        // convert from std::string to reqd PriorityType
        PriorityType priority = atof(priority_str.c_str());

        pairVec.push_back(std::make_pair(data, priority));

        // get line from input stream and store in input string
        std::getline(inStream, input);
    }

    // enqueue pairVec container into targetQueue
    //targetQueue.enqueueWithPriority(pairVec);

    return inStream;

}
```

This currently works for `stdin` or `std::cin` input however it doesn't work for `fstream` input - the very first `getline` always reads an empty line from the input such that the `while` loop never gets triggered, and I can't seem to skip it (I tried with `inStream.ignore()` as you can see above but this doesn't work.

**Edit:**

Currently I just want to get it working for file input ignoring the fact it only works for `int` data type and `double` priority type right now - these aren't relevant (and neither is the actual manipulation of the `targetQueue` object itself).

For the moment I'm just concerned with resolving the blank-line issue when trying to stream through file-input.

Example file to pass:

```
3    5.6
2    6.3
1    56.7
12   45.1
```

where the numbers on each line are `\t` separated.

Example testing:

```
#include "PriorityQueue.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void) {

    // create pq of MAX binary heap type
    PriorityQueue<int, double> pq(MAX);


    std::ifstream file("test.txt");

    file >> pq;

    std::cout << pq;

}
```

where "test.txt" is the in the format of the example file above.

**Edit: Simpler Example**

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

class Example {

public:

    Example() {}

    size_t getSize() const { return vec.size(); }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Example& example);

private:

    std::vector< std::pair<int, double> > vec;

};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Example& example) {

    int x;
    double y;
    while (is >> x >> y) {
        std::cout << "in-loop" << std::endl;
        example.vec.push_back(std::make_pair(x, y));
    }
    return is;
}

int main(void) {

    Example example;

    std::ifstream file("test.txt");

    file >> example;

    file.close();

    std::cout << example.getSize() << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. What are example file contents you might need to read?

Comment: @Barry Indeed, I have added an edit to the OP now - to re-iterate the actual manipulation of the queue is not important here, I'd just like to know how to resolve the blank line issue when reading from a file input stream.

Comment: That's part the **minimal** part. Just remove all the irrelevant stuff to the code, and show an example file that fails to do what you want.

Comment: how about adding an extra `getline` before the while loop into some temp string and then do the actual `getline` for `input`

Answer (score 1):

The operator is already overloaded -- and shall be overloaded -- for many types. Let those functions do their work:

```
template<typename Type, typename PriorityType>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inStream, PriorityQueue<Type, PriorityType>& targetQueue)
{
  std::vector< std::pair<Type, PriorityType> > pairVec;
  Type data;
  PriorityType priority;

  while(inStream >> data >> priority)
    pairVec.push_back(std::make_pair(data, priority));

  targetQueue.enqueueWithPriority(pairVec);

  return inStream;
}
```

Comment: Works well for `stdin` and `std::cin` however this still doesn't seem to work for file streaming :/

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: Really? I tested it with file streaming and it worked perfectly. If you post a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: Maybe I'm being an idiot and forgetting how to properly file stream, but I'll the test code from my `main` to the OP now

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: That still isn't a complete example. And you're sure nothing goes into `pairVec`?

Comment: If I was to post a complete example (including all necessary parts of the PriorityQueue) then it would take up far too much room. It is superfluous in this case anyway as any object type could be used in place of the PQ to achieve the same result - upon testing with file input, it seems  that the while loop is not entered at all (never gets past condition to enter the loop)

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: If that's true, then post an example that shows the result with a simpler type-- that's the "minimal" part of "minimal complete example". Would it help if I posted a complete example in which control *does* enter the loop?

Comment: I'll add a simpler (complete) example in the OP, shouldn't take too long

Comment: Simpler example added - when running in my case using the `.txt` file shown in OP, the while loop is never entered.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: Works for me: *in-loop<CR>in-loop<CR>in-loop<CR>in-loop<CR>4* Is this a minimal example? That is, if you simplify it any further, does the error vanish and the file I/O start working?

Comment: Well this is most odd, even just writing a small amount of code to compute the number of lines in the text file yields zero for me - something weird must be going on.